# How to avoid reloading Webview - if already loaded once

Tags: android, webview

### My issue

We have customized web page. Each page around 10 MB 3D files.
I want to avoid each time reload 10 MB webview page.

### What I tried

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 50 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 50MB
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
```

### Problem

It seems it just improve the 10% speed. 
It again takes more time for same page.

### Question

Is any other way possible to avoid reload the 10 MB webview again? (Like Glide)

Comment: Have you properly configured `Headers` of your page to let the web client know that the page you're providing is cacheable? I'm talking about `Cache-Control`, `Expires` and all related to caching. If not, your `WebView` client won't understand either to fully cache page or not.

Comment: have you ever tried LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK and LOAD_CACHE_ONLY for cacheMode?

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu tried LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK only. will try LOAD_CACHE_ONLY

Answer (score 2):

Two options to resolve your problem:

**Option 1.** Edit your `.htaccess` file in your webserver to include the following lines. This way the client will understand that the webpage is cachable. This way you can keep your cache mode as is. You should change `max-age` (given in seconds) and `Expires` to meet your requirements.

> .htaccess

```
<!-- Rest of code-->
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
```

If the above lines included in `.htaccess` this will work.

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
```

For reference, you can check this repo (https://github.com/mecoFarid/WebViewCache) based on this question. Exaple in this repo works since I modified `.htaccess` in server side.

---

**Option 2. (NOT RECOMMENDED)** As @Azer pointed out `LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK` and `LOAD_CACHE_ONLY`. They're both extremely dangerous. Because if cache mode is set to `LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK` that means even if resources are expired your your webview will still load cache. And if cache mode is set to `LOAD_CACHE_ONLY` same problem will persist even if you've connected network, resources will not be loaded instead, cache will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. will check & let you know.

Comment: you can have below code in on pause  public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        mWebView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    } and then before loading WebView again do the following  mWebView.restoreState(webViewBundle);

Comment: @RanjithKumar can you please, specify your use case? Is it only to survive configuration changes or you want caching to be independent of framework lifecycle?

Comment: @SusheelTickoo right. If the OP wants to survive only configuration changes or activity destruction due to memory, then that’s applicable too.

Comment: @JonGoodwin, Is this shoutout or just reminder that you can do whatever you want to do with your code?! You're right it's your code, but solving a problem documented/official way will cost you less overhead. I mean that's why the server and the client have such a simple on-liner code to relieve you from verbose

Comment: No this is me putting a comment in the wrong place ;O)

Comment: @Farid we don't have access for website. anyway bounty time expired so I offered bounty to your answer.

Comment: @RanjithKumar thanks for that, even though it proved to be of no help to your case. May I know if you got to resolve it with any other method?

Comment: @Farid no still searching. Thanks :)